# Websockets vs WebRTC for browser games. Scalability?

Tags: websocket, webrtc, game-development

Which has more scalability? I would like to support 100+ players at once. I hear WebRTC is peer-to-peer, but there's this game server library called geckos.io that somehow uses it for server authoritative architecture (don't ask me, I don't know).